# C# Portable Class Library - Eval function

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, portable-class-library

I'm looking for a JavaScript-like Eval-Method to run dynamic if conditions / calculations are created at runtime. The solution must work in a Portable Class Library.

In my non-portable project i used this:

```
System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
object result = table.Compute("2 > 1", string.Empty); //true
result = table.Compute("1+1", string.Empty); //2
```

But `System.Data.DataTable` is not available in a PCL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

ADO.NET is not supported in any traditional portable class library, which means that e.g. the `DataTable` class is not available in PCL. In the upcoming .NET Standard 2.0, which can be considered the successor of PCL, ADO.NET will be available though. Scheduled release for .NET Standard 2.0 is Q3 2017.

For now, there are a number of PCL math parser packages available, which will allow you to evaluate simple and more complex mathematical expressions.

You might want to look at one of the following:

- YAMP ([Github](https://github.com/FlorianRappl/YAMP)) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/YAMP/))
- Mathos Parser ([Github](https://github.com/MathosProject/Mathos-Parser-Portable))

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, the  solutions do not cover my requirements. After some further research I have  found a proper Eval function: https://github.com/nreco/lambdaparser . This library covers all my requirements.

Comment: Well, at least YAMP is more than well equipped to do what the NReco Parser is capable of, at least looking at the examples. But if you are content with the NReco parser, that's perfectly fine. Good luck!